Rule anything out vs Rule out anything

"I'm not ready to rule out anything at this point."
"I'm not ready to rule anything out at this point."

Is there a specific English grammar rule that makes either of these preferred or "more correct"?

Not that I am aware of. Either can be said, they both sound OK to a native speaker and are interchangeable.

There are separable and non-separable phrasal verbs. This one is separable.

Both mean the same thing. But they do have an effect on how the sentence can be constructed.
Consider the sentence with an extra adjective modifying anything:

I'm not ready to rule out anything plausible.
I'm not ready to rule anything plausible out.
*I'm not ready to rule anything out plausible. (Incorrect)
(Better: I'm not ready to rule anything out that's plausible.)

You can see how the second option might get unwieldy and hard to follow if the modifier were a longer clause. Keeping the phrasal verb "rule out" together makes its meaning clear up front and allows greater flexibility in what comes after.
This comes at the cost of de-emphasizing the phrasal verb itself. If the verb is the main focus of the sentence, it's better to put the preposition at the end (and keep the object phrase short).
